# Spring @ConfigurationProperties doesn't inject anything, field stays null

Tags: java, spring-boot, null, yaml, snakeyaml

I am trying to inject values to fields like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("paypal")
public class Paypal
{
    private List<List<List<String>>> deleterequest;

    public List<List<List<String>>> getDeleterequest()
    {
        return deleterequest;
    }

    public void setDeleterequest(List<List<List<String>>> deleterequest)
    {
        this.deleterequest = deleterequest;
    }


    private String date;

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Note: The Paypal bean itself is successfully loaded and not null. **Reading values with @Value works fine** in that class. My main class is also annotated with:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
```

But both date and deleterequest stays null in this code:

```
@Autowired
private Paypal propsPayPal;

this.propsPayPal.getDeleterequest(); //returns null (no NPE!)
this.propsPayPal.getDate(); //returns null (no NPE!)
```

In the Spring Java Config I wrote:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
{
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer o = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
    yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource(Constants.PROPERTIES_FILE_NAME));
    o.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
    return o;
}

@Bean
public Paypal paypal()
{
    return new Paypal();
}
```

and my *application.yml* looks like this:

```
paypal:
    date: Datum
    deleterequest:
    -
        -
            - Typ
            - Allgemeine Abbuchung
        -
            - Status
            - Abgeschlossen
```

Any help?

**EDIT**: I've figured out that when I create a new Spring project (just to test this issue) with an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext (which is used in my main program) as Context, it doesn't inject any values. Using a ConfigurableApplicationContext (via. SpringApplication.run(...)) works perfectly fine, variables will get injected. I have to get it to work on a AnnotationConfigApplicationContext though.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot so you should be using `@PropertySource` and not another `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as that is already loaded by Spring Boot. And you shouldn't create the bean yourself, Spring Boot will create it for you using the `@EnableConfgurationProperties(PayPal.class)`.

Comment: @M.Deinum So I have to remove the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer Bean and add the PropertySource annotation where?

Comment: On your class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Didn't work... :(

Comment: @M.Deinum I've edited my post

Comment: It is a Spring Boot feature not a plain Spring feature. So it won't work with a regular context.

Comment: Oh.. Thank you. Dumb me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to switch to a ConfigurableApplicationContext.
I used a AnnotationConfigApplicationContext which doesn't support this feature.